# Need to reverse dynamic Geo Location coordinates for use with geoJson script

Tags: php, geocoding, custom-post-type

I am using the custom post-type plugin with Wordpress. I've added the Geo Location Map extension so that in the backend, the client can enter a physical address and it will output the geo-coordinates. This works fine until I use it with the geoJson function to place marker.

Below is the script to place the marker.

```
var geoJson = [{
type: 'Feature',
"geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [-97.325741, 32.7423499]},
"properties": {
    "image": "",
    "url": "http://google.com",
    "marker-symbol": "commercial",
    "marker-color": "#ff793d",
    "marker-size": "large"
}
}];
```

The custom field should come into place like this:

```
"geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [<php? the_field('map_address'); ?>]},
```

BUT, the coordinates that are output are in the *opposite* order than they need to be for this function. They are correct for other areas where I'm using them dynamically but need to know how to swap the order that they're output here, if possible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, I fixed it using the following script. The geoJson specs do say coordinates should be formatted as X,Y everywhere but this doesn't seems to be the case for the "geometry" coordinates for a single marker. All of my markers show up where they're supposed to when the coordinates are Y,X (only for marker coordinates - setView coordinates are still X,Y).

```
<?php
$address = get_field('map_address');
$x = strtok($address, ',');
$y = strstr($address, ",");
$y = str_replace(",", "", $y);
?>
```

and then called the coordinates with,

```
"geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [<?php echo $y.",".$x; ?>]}
```

and it works!

Answer (score 2):

According to the [GeoJSON Format Specification](http://www.geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#id2):

> Point coordinates are in x, y order (easting, northing for projected coordinates, longitude, latitude for geographic coordinates)

Meaning you want your coordinates to be switched from what you have.

```
"geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [32.7423499, -97.325741]}
```

Comment: elsewhere in my scripting, yes that.s the standard order. But when placing the markers, it seems to need to coordinates as y,x. If I manually enter them as y,x then the marker shows up where it should. Doing it as x,y, the marker is in the wrong place...I know it's odd but it seems as though for that particular function to work, the coords need to by y,x.